# How to customize the format of iptable log info?

Tags: iptables, logs

```
sudo  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --sport 80 -j LOG --log-ip-options
```

To check the format of iptables log info.

```
Feb  6 20:01:32 hwy kernel: [13004.628960] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:30:40:50:40:d0:f8:32:e4:96:96:b4:08:00 SRC=183.232.24.111 DST=192.168.1.176 LEN=52 TOS=0x04 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=48659 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=33751 WINDOW=114 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

How can i customize the format of iptables log info such as :

```
Feb  6 20:01:32 hwy kernel: [13004.628960] SRC=183.232.24.111
```

Only source ip left in the log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the log format that is generated by iptables' `LOG` target.
The format is fixed in the kernel `xt_LOG` module.

An alternative could be to use the `NFLOG` target, which sends the packet through a netlink socket to a multicast group. You then need a usespace process that subscribes to the group and processes the received packets to generate your required log format.